# Syntax error in URL hack

Tags: urlhacking

I have a button on opportunity related list where i am trying URL hacking. But i am getting syntax error at `{!CASE({!Opportunity.Account_record_type_name__c},`

Rest all is working just fine. Also the Account_record_type_name__c is a text formula field which is pulling the account recordtype name. And 00N0a00000CcXpd is identifier for a Multiselect picklist.

URL hacked; button code:-

```
https://na16.salesforce.com/006/e?retURL=%2F{!Opportunity.Id}&CF00Nj000000BT6zH={!Opportunity.Name}&CF00Nj000000BT6zH_lkid={!Opportunity.Id}&opp3={!Opportunity.Name}+|+{!Opportunity.Account}&00N0a00000CcXpd={!CASE({!Opportunity.Account_record_type_name__c},"Operating Company",Buyer, "Financial Sponsor",Investor,NULL)}&RecordType=012j00000000G6J&ent=Opportunity
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this part `{!CASE({!Opportunity.Account_record_type_name__c}` to this:

```
{!CASE(Opportunity.Account_record_type_name__c
```

So that your URL will become like this:

```
https://na16.salesforce.com/006/e?retURL=%2F{!Opportunity.Id}&CF00Nj000000BT6zH={!Opportunity.Name}&CF00Nj000000BT6zH_lkid={!Opportunity.Id}&opp3={!Opportunity.Name}+|+{!Opportunity.Account}&00N0a00000CcXpd={!CASE(Opportunity.Account_record_type_name__c,"Operating Company",Buyer, "Financial Sponsor",Investor,NULL)}&RecordType=012j00000000G6J&ent=Opportunity
```